# Two rectangles next to eachother is not working (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paintcomponent, drawrect

I am trying to draw a line, but I keep getting problems. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

```
private Paint red = new Paint();
private Paint orange = new Paint();

red.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
orange.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8C00"));

canvas.drawRect(0, 400, 300, 0, red);
canvas.drawRect(300, 400, 300, 0, orange);
```

The orange bar just sits in the same spot as the red one... Why?

Comment: `drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)` .. your orange rectangle has horizontal measure of `0` (runs from 300 to 300). maybe try making your right `600` instead and see if that puts the orange rectangle where you expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see that the length of the orange rectangle (300-300) is 0 in your code. That is why you can't see it. So try this:

```
    canvas.drawRect(0, 400, 300, 0, red);
    canvas.drawRect(300, 400, 600, 0, orange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation again: [Canvas.drawRect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRec)

```
drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
Draw the specified Rect using the specified paint.
```

So your last two coordinate values (`right` and `bottom`) are NOT length but position.

Answer (score 0):

You have the top of 400 and the bottom of 0. It is strange. You might want to swap them. However, the problem is that your first line has a left bound of 0 and the right bound of 300, while the second line is an orange point, having the left bound of 300 and the right bound is exactly there, at 300.